# Calculate the expected value with of a function with given variance

Tags: probability, expected-value

Question: Let $X$ be a random variable with $E(X) = 1$ and $Var(X) = 5$. Then $E((1 + X)^2)$ = ?

We know that for any discrete variable and function $f:R \to R$ the expected value is
$$E[f(X)]= \sum_{x \in X(\Omega)} f(x)\cdot P(X=x)$$.

So in our case:
$$E[(1 + X)^2]= \sum_{x \in X(\Omega)} (1 + x)^2\cdot P(X=x)$$.

But I can't to anything with that or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to assume $X$ takes on discrete values.

Recall that $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2.$$  Then $$\operatorname{E}[(1+X)^2] = \operatorname{E}[1+2X+X^2] = 1 + 2\operatorname{E}[X] + \operatorname{E}[X^2],$$ by linearity of expectation.  So if you know $\operatorname{E}[X] = 1$ and $\operatorname{Var}[X] = 5$, you can use this information to compute $\operatorname{E}[X^2]$, from which you can substitute back into the above equation to get the desired expectation.

Comment: Oh yes how i could not see that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbb{E}[X+1]^2=\mathbb{V}[X+1]+(\mathbb{E}[X+1])^2=\mathbb{V}[X]+(\mathbb{E}[X]+1)^2=5+2^2=9$$